# Does $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$ imply $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: inequality, optimization, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

> Suppose we have real numbers $x_1, ..., x_n$ which satisfy $x_1 + ... + x_n = 1$. Do we have the lower bound $x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}$?

It seems intuitive that we can minimize this by setting all the $x_i$ to be $\frac{1}{n}$, but I can't seem to prove it.

I also couldn't find a reference to this result. I would appreciate it if anyone could provide one!

Comment: Did you try Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove that $$x_i^2\ge \frac 2n x_i - \frac{1}{n^2}$$ and sum up for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Shockingly effective. How did you come up with this?

Comment: @Sambo Since $\sum x_i = 1$, you may write the inequality as $\sum x_i^2 \ge \frac 1n + t\cdot \left(1-\sum x_i\right) = \sum \left( -tx_i + \frac 1{n^2} - \frac tn\right)$, where $t$ is an arbitrary real number. If we find $t$ such that $x_i^2 \ge -tx_i + \frac 1{n^2} - \frac tn \ (*)$ then we will be done. In the original inequality we have equality for $x_i=\frac 1n$, so we want equality in $(*)$ for $x_i=\frac 1n$ as well. Plugging in $x_i=\frac 1n$, we find $t=\frac 2n$. We are lucky because if $t=\frac 2n$ then $(*)$ holds for all $x_i$.

Comment: Despite the link to Cauchy-Schwarz being useful (and showing that (1/n, ..., 1/n) is the only solution), I chose this question as accepted since it is the most basic proof.

Answer (score 5):

By C-S
$$\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n1\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2\geq\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2=\frac{1}{n}.$$
We can use also the Tangent Line method:
$$\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2-\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k^2-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(x_k+\frac{1}{n}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left(x_k-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(x_k+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{2}{n}\left(x_k-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\geq0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use that $$\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}\le \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2}{n}}$$ .

Answer (score 2):

Another useful inequality is [Chebyshev's one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chebyshev%27s_Inequality)
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ib_i\geq \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i\right)$$
for $a_1\geq a_2 \geq ... \geq a_n$ and $b_1\geq b_2 \geq ... \geq b_n$

We can always re-organise $x_i$ in descending order $x_1\geq x_2 \geq ... \geq x_n$ and this won't affect $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ values. As a result

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_ix_i \geq \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)=\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Basically use the variance is non-negative bound. That is for any random variable,
$$E[X^2]\ge E[X]^2$$

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values $x_1$ to $x_n$ with equal probability. Can you handle the rest?